# AbsSpinner NullPointerExceptin on 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()

Tags: java, android

Crashlytics is showing following exception on our Android App(unusually high number of crashes), I am not able to figure out where this issue is happening inside my app and how to avoid this.

We have thoroughly tested our App in different devices but we were not able to reproduce this crash (we only see this Crashlytics). Interestingly we see this issue on all Android OS's except for Lollipop.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference

android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure (AbsSpinner.java:196)
android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure (Spinner.java:580)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure (AppCompatSpinner.java:419)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.measureChildCollapseMargins (Toolbar.java:1549)
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onMeasure (Toolbar.java:1657)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure (AppBarLayout.java:220)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure (DrawerLayout.java:1081)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1465)
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:748)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:630)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5972)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:194)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure (PhoneWindow.java:2693)
android.view.View.measure (View.java:18916)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2231)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1307)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1198)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6268)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:873)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:676)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:606)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:859)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:168)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5885)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:797)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Please add the code which is causing the crash. It would be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: @ArunShankar That is the challenge I am having, crash log(shown above) obtained from Crashlytics Tool doesn't show where exactly in my code is the problem and I also don't know when this crash is happening.

I am looking at all the places where ever Spinner is used to see if I can find something.